# Mysql2 Ruby: No implicit conversion Array/Hash - INSERT statement

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

I'm trying to learn mysql2 ruby gem usage and I have encoutered this problem:

> no implicit conversion of Array into Hash (TypeError)

When executing the INSERT query:

```
client.query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(Name TEXT, Value INT)")
client.query("INSERT INTO test VALUES (?,?)", ["abc",3])
```

I'm coming from sqlite, and using the same syntax was working fine. Can't understand what's happening here...

Answer (score 1):

You can use prepared statemets for this (as documented on mysql2 gem [github](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) page)

```rb
statement = client.prepare("INSERT INTO test (Name, Value) VALUES (?,?)")
statement.execute("abc", 3)
```

Comment: Thanks. The correct syntax is 

`statement = client.prepare("INSERT INTO test (Name, Value) VALUES (?,?)")

statement.execute("abc", 3)`

Comment: Sorry, copied a wrong line to the answer. It's corrected now.